# SQL - Combine 4 columns into one new column as a single JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Edit: FYI. So my PrimaryImage is actually an int and is used as a foreign key to my Images table. I just wanted to explain that so it is clear why I set it to `on f.PrimaryImage = i.Id`. For some reason all my rows are getting populated with every i.Id, i.EntityId, i.ImageTypeId, & i.ImageUrl instead of just where my f.PrimaryImage = i.Id.

I am writing a SQL stored procedure to SELECT ALL and I want to combine my last 4 columns `Id, EntityId, ImageTypeId, ImageUrl` into one new column `PrimaryImage` as a single JSON object. I was able to successfully do that with my Skills column but for that I needed it as an array that holds JSON objects so simply using `"FOR JSON AUTO"` took care of that. But like I said for `PrimaryImage`, I need that as a single JSON object that contains my `Id, EntityId, ImageTypeId, & ImageUrl`. I included a picture of my result after executing this proc and right below my table I drew a representation of what I want the column to look like. Just to clarify I have four tables my Friends, FriendSkills, Skills, & Images tables which I've used join statements organize accordingly. Basically my schema needs to look like this:

```
{
"id": 0000,
"userId": "String"
"bio": "String",
"title": "String",
"summary": "String",
"headline": "String",
"statusId": "String",
"slug": "String",
"skills": [{id: 0, name: "String"},{id: 0, name: "String"}],
"primaryImage": {
          "id": 0,
          "entityId": 0,
          "imageTypeId": 0,
          "imageUrl": "String"
        }
}
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Friends_SelectAllV2]


AS

/* --- Test Proc ------

Execute dbo.Friends_SelectAllV2

*/

BEGIN

    Select  f.Id
            ,f.UserId
            ,f.DateAdded
            ,f.DateModified
            ,f.Title
            ,f.Bio
            ,f.Summary
            ,f.Headline
            ,f.Slug
            ,f.StatusId
            ,Skills = ( SELECT s.Id,
                        s.Name
                        From dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills fs
                        on s.Id = fs.SkillId
                        Where  f.Id = fs.FriendId
                        FOR JSON AUTO
            ),
            PrimaryImage = (SELECT i.Id,
                            i.EntityId,
                            i.ImageTypeId,
                            i.ImageUrl
                            From dbo.Friends f left join dbo.Images as i
                            on f.PrimaryImage = i.Id
                            Where f.PrimaryImage = i.Id
                            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
            )
            
    
END
```

Comment: You can do the same thing for the new `primaryImage` column.

Comment: Basically the same as for the `Skills` column, just add `without_array_wrapper`.

Comment: @ShawnFetanat, the approach is the same (something like `primaryImage = (SELECT i.Id, i.EntityId, i.ImageTypeId, i.ImageUrl FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)`), I just missed the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` explanations. But one possible issue is the escaping of the urls. I posted this as a comment, because thera are many questions at stackoverflow.com about the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: For the record no answers here have been helpful. @Zhorov probably forgot to mention that using WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER does NOT generate valid JSON text UNLESS there is one row and only one row. That's probably why I am getting all JSON objects in each row instead of just where my f.PrimaryImage = i.Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't actually need another subquery if the inner property is a single object, you can use `FOR JSON PATH` with explicit path syntax.**

```sql
Select       f.Id
            ,f.UserId
            ,f.DateAdded
            ,f.DateModified
            ,f.Title
            ,f.Bio
            ,f.Summary
            ,f.Headline
            ,f.Slug
            ,f.StatusId
            ,Skills = ( SELECT s.Id,
                        s.Name
                        From dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills fs
                        on s.Id = fs.SkillId
                        Where  f.Id = fs.FriendId
                        FOR JSON AUTO
            ),
            i.Id AS [PrimaryImage.Id],
            i.EntityId AS [PrimaryImage.EntityId],
            i.ImageTypeId AS [PrimaryImage.ImageTypeId],
            i.ImageUrl AS [PrimaryImage.ImageUrl]
From dbo.Friends f
left join dbo.Images as i on f.PrimaryImage = i.Id
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

If however there are multiple images, and you need a subquery, the issue here is that you are putting the whole `Friends` table in again, instead of correlating the outside table. You would also remove `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`.

```sql
    Select  f.Id
            ,f.UserId
            ,f.DateAdded
            ,f.DateModified
            ,f.Title
            ,f.Bio
            ,f.Summary
            ,f.Headline
            ,f.Slug
            ,f.StatusId
            ,Skills = ( SELECT s.Id,
                        s.Name
                        From dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills fs
                        on s.Id = fs.SkillId
                        Where  f.Id = fs.FriendId
                        FOR JSON AUTO
            ),
            PrimaryImage = (SELECT i.Id,
                            i.EntityId,
                            i.ImageTypeId,
                            i.ImageUrl
                            FROM dbo.Images as i
                            WHERE f.PrimaryImage = i.Id
                            FOR JSON PATH
            )
    From dbo.Friends f
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```